# Bind_param() on a non-object-error when using variables as input

Tags: php, mysqli

trying to do an update using mysqli, by calling a class function like this:

```
$nyVaegt = 10;
$navn = 'Ord';

$nyOevelse = new oevelse();
$nyOevelse->opdaterOevelse( $nyVaegt, $navn );
```

And this is the corresponding class function:

```
public function opdaterOevelse (
        $nyVaegt,
        $navn)

    {
        $this->nyVaegt = $nyVaegt;
        $this->navn = $navn;

        global $mysqli;

        $stmtopdaterOevelseIHistorik = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE oevelser SET `vaegt12reps`=? WHERE `navn`='?' VALUES (?, ?)");
        var_dump($stmtopdaterOevelseIHistorik);
        $stmtopdaterOevelseIHistorik->bind_param(
                "ds", 
                $nyVaegt,
                $navn);

        $stmtopdaterOevelseIHistorik->execute();

if ( $stmtopdaterOevelseIHistorik )
       echo "Query success!<br>";
   else
       echo "Query failed!<br>";

      }
```

If I run it like this, it fails saying that:

```
Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object
```

The error refers to this line:

```
$stmtopdaterOevelseIHistorik->bind_param(
```

var_dump responds: bool(false)

So, something goes wrong while binding the parameters, it seems.

If I bypass the variables and call like this:

```
$stmtopdaterOevelseIHistorik = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE oevelser SET `vaegt12reps`=100 WHERE `navn`='Ord'");
```

it works fine...

Tried all kinds of '', ""-variations, but I can't make it work... - any advice from you good people of SO...?

Comment: Basic debugging: You realize `$stmtopdaterOevelseIHistorik` is null.. step back until you find where it SHOULD be set. `$mysqli->prepare()`.. ok that's failing. [Let's look up the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). "Returns FALSE if an error occurred" - OK how do I debug a false return value from prepare()... go from there

Comment: @Fred-ii- - much appreciated, of course I shouldn't add values, works fine now without, thx a million - sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees...

Comment: @ErikLassen You're welcome Erik. I had deleted my comments and posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Far as I know, UPDATE doesn't use VALUES:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html
- INSERT does: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Plus, remove the quotes in `='?'` which is the main cause for:

> Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Change your existing line to the following:

```
$stmtopdaterOevelseIHistorik = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE oevelser SET `vaegt12reps`=? WHERE `navn`=?");
```