# INSERT INTO mysqli returns non-object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert

EDITED!

Been looking at posts with similar issues, but can't seem to find an answer that applies to my situation - hope you guys can help.

UPDATE: Have updated my code based on inputs - thanks! And I'm seeing progress, but:

Now, below I'm getting the error  `Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object` only when the INSERT INTO is called inside the `while`-loop.

$stmtTjekFindesOevelse, $stmtFindOevelsesID and $stmtGemNyVaegtOgRepsSet work fine by themselves (when fed variables manually inside the code) Only when inside the while loop $stmtGemNyVaegtOgRepsSet fails with above error message.

The $stmtFindOevelsesID will always return an integer (the id). If there isn't such an id, it will be discovered by the `if ($stmtTjekFindesOevelse->num_rows() > 0)` and the code will not run.

Guess there's an issue with the while-loop - just don't know which alternative to use in this case...

```
    $navn = 'Brystpres';
    $vaegt = 10;
    $reps = 11;
    $antalGangeUdfoert = 11;

    global $mysqli;

        $stmtTjekFindesOevelse = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM oevelser WHERE navn=?");
        $stmtTjekFindesOevelse->bind_param("s", $navn);
        $stmtTjekFindesOevelse->execute();
        $stmtTjekFindesOevelse->store_result();

if ($stmtTjekFindesOevelse->num_rows() > 0)   
{

    $stmtFindOevelsesID = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM oevelser WHERE navn=?");
    $stmtFindOevelsesID->bind_param("s", $navn);
    $stmtFindOevelsesID->execute();
    $stmtFindOevelsesID->bind_result($oevelsesID);

while ($stmtFindOevelsesID->fetch()) {


$stmtGemNyVaegtOgRepsSet = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO vaegtogreps (oevelsesreference, vaegt, reps, antalgangeudfoert) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

    $stmtGemNyVaegtOgRepsSet->bind_param("idii", $oevelsesID, $vaegt, $reps, $antalGangeUdfoert);

    $stmtGemNyVaegtOgRepsSet->execute();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong [**identifiers**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) for your columns.

```
('oevelsesreference', 'vaegt', 'reps', 'antalgangeudfoert')
```

Either by removing the quotes

```
(oevelsesreference, vaegt, reps, antalgangeudfoert)
```

or using backticks around the column names:

```
(`oevelsesreference`, `vaegt`, `reps`, `antalgangeudfoert`)
```

Having used error checking on your query would have signaled that.

Change:

```
$stmtGemNyVaegtOgRepsSet->execute();
```

to:

```
if(!$stmtGemNyVaegtOgRepsSet->execute()){
trigger_error("There was an error....".$mysqli->error, E_USER_WARNING);
}
```

in order to get the reason for the error.

---

**Edit:**

I believe I found the solution, which worked for me and it inserted the following in "vaegtogreps" table.

```
oevelsesreference   vaegt   reps    antalgangeudfoert
       1             10      11            11
```

You need to use `store_result()` for your second SELECT.

Simply add `$stmtFindOevelsesID->store_result();` to it:

```
$stmtFindOevelsesID = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM oevelser WHERE navn=?");
$stmtFindOevelsesID->bind_param("s", $navn);
$stmtFindOevelsesID->execute();
$stmtFindOevelsesID->bind_result($oevelsesID);

// added and working
$stmtFindOevelsesID->store_result();
```

Comment: Thanks - the quotes were actually added as a test, but thanks for pointing out that I need to use backticks. Had previously tried without (and now with the correct backticks) bit still getting the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: @ErikLassen You're welcome. Are you sure that `$mysqli` is your DB connection? Many times it's because of a bad connection to DB.

Comment: @ErikLassen `$stmtGemNyVaegtOgRepsSet->conn->error;` that doesn't seem right, try and remove it.

Comment: @ErikLassen I'm thinking that `$stmtGemNyVaegtOgRepsSet->conn->error;` is interferring with your query. Did you remove it as I asked? Plus, where are `$vaegt, $reps, $antalGangeUdfoert` coming from?

Comment: @Fred-ii- quite odd, the select above the insertion works, and the query is now fine inside the preparation, but still errors, lol :D

Comment: @Ghost That's what I don't get also. However, I'm thinking that `$stmtGemNyVaegtOgRepsSet->conn->error;` is interferring with it, what do you think? That doesn't look kosher to me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah can cause errors as i don't think it has a `-
>conn` property, but i don't think it will give the same error as `Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object`

Comment: @Ghost I'm wondering if the OP is using a seperate function as he did in his other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/26347076/ one that I had given an answer for. Scope issue? Plus, I think `$stmtGemNyVaegtOgRepsSet->conn->error;` should be removed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- could be a factor also, but in that question, it has its `global` usage. its just its weird because the first preparation worked fine. yeah could just ditch that `$stmtGemNyVaegtOgRepsSet->conn->error;`

Comment: @Ghost It just makes it that much more harder when we're not hearing anything more from the OP. But now Twist added something interesting, using `idi` instead of `idii`, what do you think, an AI issue? EDIT: Scratch that, he (or she) removed it.

Comment: @ErikLassen The `d` in `bind_param("idii"` stands for "double", that could be an additional factor. Try changing it to `bind_param("isii"` or when in doubt, even having all `s`'s should work, so try also `bind_param("ssss"` - At this point, I'm out of options.

Comment: Hi guys - sorry you haven't heard back - had to go cook dinner for my son ;)

I tried removing the $stmtGemNyVaegtOgRepsSet->conn->error; to no avail. Will try "isii" even though I'm pretty sure about the double and look at the potential AI issue, as mentioned by @Fred-ii- 

Will experiment some more come tomorrow, thanks a million for your inputs so far :)

Comment: @ErikLassen You're welcome Erik; food before work ;) I'll see what I can do to setup a similar DB in order to get this going. I'll keep you posted either way.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're right about the food - also, a 10 month old can be pretty loud when hungry, so better feed him when getting close to dinner time ;)

Comment: @ErikLassen I would believe it Erik. It's best to keep the young lad happy ;) Now, I believe I found the solution to the problem. Reload my answer and look under **Edit**, the details are in there. *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's awesome, it works! :) Thanks a million for going that extra mile to help me out - hope to one day be skilled enough to help you out ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO vaegtogreps ('oevelsesreference', 'vaegt', 'reps', 'antalgangeudfoert')
                         ^                 ^  ^     ^  ^    ^  ^                 ^
```

The quotes for columns are backticks not single quotes:

```
`column1`, `column2` // backticks
```

So either you omit them or use backticks:

```
INSERT INTO vaegtogreps (`oevelsesreference`, `vaegt`, `reps`, `antalgangeudfoert`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Love the graphic feature ;) G'day Ghost. +1 from me, *cheers* Didn't know you were formulating an answer too.

Comment: Thanks - the quotes were actually added as a test, but thanks for pointing out that I need to use backticks. Had previously tried without (and now with the correct backticks) bit still getting the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: @ErikLassen thats odd, you sure thats the only codes you have?

Comment: @Ghost I finally figured out what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the error you get:
    `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object`
and
    `Trying to get property of non-object`
it seems you don't correctly instanciate your mysqli connection.

Try to do it like that, as mentioned here in the [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("dbhost", "dbuser", "dbpass", "dbname");  

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();  
}
```

Comment: The OP states *"the SELECT works fine, btw."* So, it doesn't seem to be a connection error.